# Unwrap hibernate entity

Tags: hibernate

Having only reference to hibernate entity how could I unwrap pojo under the hibernate proxy?
I'm trying to foolish hibernate and make some object modification invisible for the framework.

Comment: This is the 3rd time you've posted this question in the last hour. I would suggest expanding on what it is you are trying to achieve and you might then get some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why would someone do that.

But if you'd like to update object without persisting it, just make sure it's detached or transient.
See the [official docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en-US/html/objectstate.html#objectstate-overview) for possible object states.

In fact you can detach explicitly.

In JPA:

```
EntityManager em;
...
em.detach(entity);
// now modify your entity fields without letting hibernate persistent the changes
```

For more info see: [JPA Explicit detach](http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/persistence/detach#Explicit_Detach_)

**UPDATE**:

Alternatively, folks at JBoss seem to have pluggable implementation for deciding if object is/is not dirty: [org.hibernate.CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/javadoc/7.1.2.Final/org/hibernate/CustomEntityDirtinessStrategy.html). If you're not in JBoss, or on the specific version (seems to apply to 7.1.2) this could serve for inspiration purposes at least.

Comment: so load whatever you need prio to detaching (just by accessing the field/iterating the reffered collection), that should be it

Comment: let say I have deep object tree, and I don't know beforehand what to preload. Existing application architecture uses lazy loading heavily.